# Can Bran warg into white walkers or wights?

Tags: game-of-thrones, a-song-of-ice-and-fire

As we have Bran warg into animals and humans. Can he warg into white walkers or wights?

Comment: Our only clue is Coldhands. *If* he's currently being warged, then yes, it's possible; however it is unknown at this time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

He has not done it within the books or the films yet. As to feasibility...

### White Walkers

It seems unlikely. Bran's ability to warg into humans has thus far been limited to Hodor, an individual of limited mental capacity, and he had great difficulty with that. The White Walkers seem to be fully intelligent, so the odds are that he would not be able to warg into them.

### Wights

[Wights](http://gameofthrones.wikia.com/wiki/Wight) have not shown any great signs of intelligence, but they have shown some small amount of awareness and independence when it comes to fulfilling orders, such as how a reanimated member of the Night Watch knew the way to the Commander's office. This suggests that they probably do have a mind to overcome and additionally, it seems to be a diminished mind, much like an animal or Hodor.

**TL;DR**, Unlikely and Maybe.

Comment: But another Warg has been shown in the books to warg into a human as well, it's just most likely more difficult.

Comment: @kuhl is correct. The Warg in question is [Varamyr Six Skins](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Varamyr) and he warged into a fully intelligent woman named [Thistle](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Thistle).  I do not believe intelligence of the target comes into play here. It's the willingness of the target to host the warg which is why dogs are easiest, not the intelligence. Thistle successfully threw an expert like Varamyr out. Even hodor can feel Bran in him and he just slinks off to a corner of his mind when Bran comes and reassures him that he will give the body back